# Spring boot application is getting hangs with @Async process

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, process

Here is the code snippet. Application will start works once I restart the app, but again the app will gets hang after 20 to 30 min.

**-- service class**

```
@Async("defaultExecutor")
  public void process(Request req) {
    /// application logic

}


@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

  @Bean("defaultExecutor")
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {        

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(20);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new 
    ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);        
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }

}        

This app will run as an async process and updates the database and sends notifications.
```

logs:

```
2018-09-25 11:02:33 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
2018-09-25 11:02:33 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
2018-09-25 11:02:38 [idle_connection_reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
```

Comment: Can you try removing bean name from method process just have only @Async

Comment: Thanks. If we remove the @Bean("defaultExecutor") only one request will process at a time and it wouldn't support the concurrent requests.